# Querying the same column for 3 different values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying hard to extract the data in the format I need, but unsuccessful til now.

I have the following table

id_ticket, date_ticket, office_ticket, status_ticket

I need the query to return me, for EVERY MONTH, and always for the same OFFICE:

- the number of tickets (COUNT) with any status
- the number of tickets (COUNT) with status = 5
- the number of tickets (COUNT) with status = 6
- Month
- Year

The query I made to return ONLY the total amount of tickets with any status was this. It worked!

```
SELECT
COUNT (id_ticket) as TotalTicketsPerMonth,
'sYear' = YEAR (date_ticket),
'sMonth' = MONTH (date_ticket)
FROM crm_vw_Tickets
WHERE office_ticket = 1
GROUP BY
YEAR (date_ticket), MONTH (date_ticket)
ORDER BY sYear ASC, sMonth ASC
```

Returning the total amount of ticket with status=5

```
SELECT
COUNT (id_ticket) as TotalTicketsPerMonth,
'sYear' = YEAR (date_ticket),
'sMonth' = MONTH (date_ticket)
FROM crm_vw_Tickets
WHERE office_ticket = 1 AND status_ticket = 5
GROUP BY
YEAR (date_ticket), MONTH (date_ticket)
ORDER BY sYear ASC, sMonth ASC
```

But I need the return to be something like:

```
Year Month Total Status5 Status6
2018   1     15      5        3

2018   2     14      4        5

2018   3     19      2        8
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: [Carnac the Magnificent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnac_the_Magnificent) predicts that you will want one row for each month even if there were no tickets for that year/month/office combination.

Comment: Maybe I will! :) How can I solve this? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. You can use a `CASE` Expression to get what you need:

```
SELECT
    COUNT (id_ticket) as TotalTicketsPerMonth,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status_ticket = 5 THEN 1 END) as Status5,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status_ticket = 6 THEN 1 END) as Status6,
    'sYear' = YEAR (date_ticket),
    'sMonth' = MONTH (date_ticket)
FROM crm_vw_Tickets
WHERE office_ticket = 1
GROUP BY YEAR (date_ticket), MONTH (date_ticket)
ORDER BY sYear ASC, sMonth ASC
```

Comment: Thanks JNevill! Right on the spot! Saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

The following code builds off JNevill's answer to include summary rows for "missing" months, i.e. those with no tickets, as well as months with tickets. The basic idea is to create a table of all of the months from the first to the last ticket, `outer join` the ticket data with the months and then summarize the data. (*Tally table*, *numbers table* and *calendar table* are more or less applicable terms.)

It is a Common Table Expression (CTE) that contains several queries that work step-by-step toward the result. You can see the results of the intermediate steps by replacing the final `select` statement with one of the ones commented out above it.

```
-- Sample data.
declare @crm_vw_Tickets as Table ( id_ticket Int Identity, date_ticket Date, office_ticket Int, status_ticket Int );
insert into @crm_vw_Tickets ( date_ticket, office_ticket, status_ticket ) values
  ( '20190305', 1, 6 ), -- Shrove Tuesday.
  ( '20190501', 1, 5 ), -- May Day.
  ( '20190525', 1, 5 ); -- Towel Day.
select * from @crm_vw_Tickets;

-- Summarize the data.
with
  -- Get the minimum and maximum ticket dates for   office_ticket   1.
  Limits as (
    select Min( date_ticket ) as MinDateTicket, Max( date_ticket ) as MaxDateTicket
      from @crm_vw_Tickets
      where office_ticket = 1 ),
  -- 0 to 9.
  Ten ( Number ) as ( select * from ( values (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9) ) as Digits( Number ) ),
  -- 100 rows.
  TenUp2 ( Number ) as ( select 42 from Ten as L cross join Ten as R ),
  -- 10000 rows.  We'll assume that 10,000 months should cover the reporting range.
  TenUp4 ( Number ) as ( select 42 from TenUp2 as L cross join TenUp2 as R ),
  -- 1 to the number of months to summarize.
  Numbers ( Number ) as ( select top ( select DateDiff( month, MinDateTicket, MaxDateTicket ) + 1 from Limits ) Row_Number() over ( order by ( select NULL ) ) from TenUp4 ),
  -- Starting date of each month to summarize.
  Months as (
    select DateAdd( month, N.Number - 1, DateAdd( day, 1 - Day( L.MinDateTicket ), L.MinDateTicket ) ) as StartOfMonth
      from Limits as L cross join
        Numbers as N ),
  -- All tickets assigned to the appropriate month and a row with NULL ticket data
  --   for each month without tickets.
  MonthsAndTickets as (
    select M.StartOfMonth, T.*
      from Months as M left outer join
        @crm_vw_Tickets as T on M.StartOfMonth <= T.date_ticket and T.date_ticket < DateAdd( month, 1, M.StartOfMonth ) )
  -- Use one of the following   select   statements to see the intermediate or final results:
  --select * from Limits;
  --select * from Ten;
  --select * from TenUp2;
  --select * from TenUp4;
  --select * from Numbers;
  --select * from Months;
  --select * from MonthsAndTickets;
  select Year( StartOfMonth ) as SummaryYear, Month( StartOfMonth ) as SummaryMonth,
    Count( id_ticket ) as TotalTickets,
    Coalesce( Sum( case when status_ticket = 5 then 1 end ), 0 ) as Status5Tickets,
    Coalesce( Sum( case when status_ticket = 6 then 1 end ), 0 ) as Status6Tickets
    from MonthsAndTickets
    where office_ticket = 1 or office_ticket is NULL -- Handle months with no tickets.
    group by StartOfMonth
    order by StartOfMonth;
```

Note that the final `select` uses `Count( id_ticket )`, `Coalesce` and an explicit check for `NULL` to produce appropriate output values (`0`) for months with no tickets.

Comment: Wow! Thank you HABO! I need to take some time to understand your code, as I´m a basic level user. Let´s dig in!